# How to use special charakters like ° in heading of a letter

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

How to set an address with an ° (degree sign) on `scrlttr2`?

Let's have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=a4,DIN]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
    Main Street 1\\
    55555 Springfield)}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jack ° Jones \\
    2nd Street 15 \\
    55555 Springfield}
\opening{Hi Jack,}
\closing{Yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Inside `\begin{letter]` there is an `°` which is causing issues when compiling

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:° not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This also happens when I'm trying to use the package `units` with something like

```
\unit[99]{°}
```

or `\textcelcius` out of `textcomp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `siunitx` which offers `\degree` and `\celsius`

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=a4,DIN]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
    Main Street 1\\
    55555 Springfield)}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jack \si{\degree} Jones \\
    2nd Street 15 \\
    55555 Springfield}
\opening{Hi Jack,}
\SI{99}{\celsius}
\closing{Yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`utf8.def` from package `inputenc` only supports characters, which are used in one of the declared output encodings. Otherwise LaTeX would not know, how to print the character. `°` is defined in `TS1` encoding, which can be loaded by package `textcomp`:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=a4,DIN]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
    Main Street 1\\
    55555 Springfield)}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jack ° Jones \\
    2nd Street 15 \\
    55555 Springfield}
\opening{Hi Jack,}
\closing{Yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is not working on my setup.

Comment: @frian It *is* working, see my updated answer. Thus you have another problem, not shown in the MWE of the question.

Comment: Ahh... verified. I used it in combination with `\textcelcius` which failed due to undefined control sequence.

Comment: @frian `\textcelsius` is defined by package `textcomp` or font encoding `TS1`.